# Add resolver in Ivy

Tags: java, dependencies, ivy, dependency-management

I'm new to Ivy and I'm just trying to add a [resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html) to my `ivysettings.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ivysettings>
<settings defaultResolver="maven" />
<resolvers>
    <chain name="maven" returnFirst="true">
        <ibiblio name="restlet" m2compatible="true"
            root="http://maven.restlet.org/" />
    </chain>
</resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

The problem is that once I do that I'm not able to resolve dependencies anywhere else that in the newly added repository.

I would like to **keep** the defaults resolver and **add** a new resolver?

How can I tell Ivy to keep looking in it's default repositories?

From the [documentation I can read](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html):

> Ivy comes with a set of built-in dependency resolvers that handle most common needs.

Fine but where can I get the list of those built in resolvers !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have multiple resolvers using chain-resolvers

[REFERENCE](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/multiple.html)

Comment: `<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
        <ibiblio name="scalatools" root="http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases" m2compatible="true"/>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="org.scala-lang" resolver="scalatools"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>`